# Cant remove nginx?

Tags: python, nginx, digital-ocean

I am trying to remove nginx and resinstall so I can add an nginx module. I get an error after trying to run several commands, nginx still remains, I recently manually deleted the nginx folder, and it's still installed.

I have tried the following commands

```
sudo apt-get autoremove nginx
sudo apt-get --purge remove nginx
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get remove nginx-core nginx-full nginx-light nginx-extras nginx-naxsi nginx-common
```

---

This is the result when invoking those commands.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove nginx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  nginx
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 60 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 87.0 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Setting up python2.7-minimal (2.7.3-0ubuntu3.5) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 562, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 544, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 271, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 246, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 236, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 577, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 476, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 355, in _init_posix
    raise IOError(msg)
IOError: invalid Python installation: unable to open /usr/local/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h (No such file or directory)
dpkg: error processing python2.7-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python2.7-minimal
' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I don't understand what to do with this error message/messages?

Comment: what does `which python` and `python --version` give you?

Comment: 1. `which python` = `/usr/local/bin/python` 2. `python --version` = 2.7.3

Comment: Should I uninstall python aswell?

Comment: I don't really know, it sounds like your python install is a little wonky. Maybe uninstall and reinstall it?

Comment: Yeah when I type `python` I got all kinds of weird errors. Invalid python installation. I am having a hard time finding a way to uninstall then install on centos(digital ocean)

Comment: I cant even remove python it looks like.... ugh this is frustrating.

Comment: So I just destroyed my server droplet and made an entire new one. Not a big deal as of yet I didn't have any production/business tied into that server it was just more of a practice server but this is definitely a lesson learned.. Back up your server when it's in ideal form before moving on.

Comment: Can you please make a short answer and accept it so it doesn't show unanswered with an upvote in search?